# Acer Aspire 7535-5020 battery

Tags: batteries

I need to replace my Acer Aspire 7535-5020 battery.  The original battery has the spec: 10.8V, 4400mAh, 48Wh.

The Acer Website says: ["6-cell battery pack"](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/2009/acer/aspire/Aspire7535/Aspire7535sp2.shtml)

The [Quick guide](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/Manuals/acer/2009/UserGuides/AS_7535_7235_QG_Eng_0320.pdf) for my model says:

- 3.36 kg (7.4 lbs.) with one HDD and 8-cell battery pack
- 3.25 kg (7.1 lbs.) with one HDD and 6-cell battery pack

But this includes 7535/7235

Amazon has several choices:

- [Bavvo 14.8v,8 cells](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058KANP4)
- [Bavvo 11.1v,6 cells](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058KEWPQ)

The first choice warns:

```
This battery is not compatible with 10.8V or 11.1V original batteries.
Before purchase please make sure all the technical specifications and
the model No. match with your laptop battery.
```

The second choice has a similar warning for 14.4v and 14.8v.  But there are no other technical specifications to check -- and neither is 10.8v.  Anyone know more information on how I can be sure what battery I need?

Comment: If there is a better site for this question, let me know.

Comment: Try http://superuser.com/. In any case it doesn't belong here. We're doing electronics design. Shopping questions are off-topic and this one will be closed. You can also delete the question yourself.

Comment: Any 10.8V or 11.1V pack that fits and is said to be for your model will work. 10.8/3 = 3.6V and 11.1/3 = 3.7V. They are the same inside voltage wise - just differenrt ways of lokking at them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that Acer has documented two configurations for battery sources depending on peripheral power requirements, **I recommend you choose the higher power rated battery**, so that it will provide a higher cell voltage and thus a lower Amp load. This  which will achieve a longer battery operation time in Hours.

The DC-DC converter inside the laptop is designed for this range of cell voltages and Acer have specified both are suitable.

From your ref link:

```
Power 
subsystem
• ACPI 3.0
• 71 W 4800 mAh*
• 48.8 W 4400 mAh*
• 3-pin 65 W AC adapter*
• 3-pin 90 W AC adapter * Only for certain models*
```

If we assume worst case your laptop consumed 48W from a 71W power source and we know it is 8 cell vs 6 cell. Let us assume the current average drops accordingly 6/8 from internal SMPS DC-DC, thus for 4800mAh rating you can expect 8/6 longer hr operation. Actual mileage may vary depending on actual design of MOBO and quality of battery but there is no risk of damage indicated.

You ought to get a bigger universal battery charger too with a high capacity to reduce charge time. These come in a wide range now with 65W, 85W, 105W 125W readily avail. with many DC plugs included and some with variable cell voltage switches. Also 3rd party universal chargers are much less expensive now than OEM.

Comment: If the question is off-topic the answer should also be..

Comment: I understood the rules of this forum were to help the user on engineering related questions, not be  judgemental on helpers. Your assumption and opinion is fallacious at best.

Comment: I'm not judging *you*, I was talking about the *answer*. It's a shopping question, not engineering related, in the sense of the site's purpose.

Comment: I assumed it was engineering and was concerned about damaging with overvoltage of 8 cells vs 6

Comment: @TonyStewart - If you keep going at that rate you'll end up sounding like me in no time :-).

Comment: @Federico: I don't think it's fair to downvote a answer only because it is for a question that shouldn't have been asked.  Downvote the question and/or vote to close the question instead.  Downvote the answer only if you think it was a bad answer on its own for the question asked.

Comment: Ah refreshing logic..I share the sentiment with my seasoned colleagues Russ and Olin

Comment: +1 - the question may be off topic, but nothing wrong with this answer.